Precision calculation for Test data
I have a trained multiclassification (4 different labels) ML model for which I calculated Accuracy and Precision using Confusion Matrix . Now for the developed model, I give some test data without label. It returns me the count for all 4 labels(classification). In this case, since I do not know the TP and FP, how can I calculate the Precision? Should Precision be calculated only for the validation data? Pls help

What is called "test data" in the literature when it comes to performance assessment is data where true labels are known. Often they come from splitting up the available data with labels into different sets training/validation/test data, all with given labels.

Prediction quality is a function of both the predictions and the correct answers.
You cannot score model performance if you do not know the correct answers. Your predictions could be correct every time, or every one of them could be incorrect. Without the right answers, you don’t know.
